# Is it OK for an employee to use employer's stock images for personal projects?

Tags: professionalism, legal

If an employee has access to stock images through the employer, is it OK to use them for his own personal projects or non-commercial use?

For example, if he makes his own app or creates a website, is it permissible to use these stock images in it?

Comment: Voting to close as this is asking for legal advice... but seriously... how can you possibly think this is either legal or ethical??

Comment: @PhilipKendall, I don't think it is that's why I'm asking. And remember not everyone understands how licensing works.

Comment: Easiest way to think about it OP is that those images are company property.  They belong to your employer.  Licensing is technically in a simplest sense, understanding who has legal rights to intellectual and or  physical / digital  products. In this case, the photos.

Comment: Reopen request for this question is being discussed on [meta](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4804/3192).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No.

Images are licensed to someone, in this case your employer. That doesn't mean that they are licensed to you.

This question really isn't different than asking if you can use your employer's copy of Office or Photoshop on your home computer because you "have access to it".

In other words, what you're suggesting is illegal.

Comment: I'm not suggesting anything, I was just asking.

Comment: Are you seriously suggesting it is illegal if I use my employer provided Excel for my daughter's classroom treat schedule? By that logic, jotting down a note with a company pen is illegal because I'm using up ink paid for by the company. This answer starts off good, but diverges quickly. Very quickly.

Comment: @corsiKa Pens don't have license terms.

Comment: @corsiKa If you install it on your computer outside of the company's license,yes it's illegal.

Comment: @S.Grey Don't give them any ideas!! I already barely own half the things in my house due to restrictive licenses.

Comment: Actually using office and photoshop may be ok as long as you are doing it on your company computer.  try to use the licence on your home pc thats where you break the law.

Comment: @corsiKa To find out the pen's license terms, ask the person in charge of supplies "May I take this pen out of the office?"